# POST method array

Tags: php, post

I have a problem with creating array on POST method. Code:

```
<input class='form-control' name='ern[".$row['ID']."][value]' type='text' placeholder='€'>


$comp = isset($_GET['comp']) ? $_GET['comp'] : false;
$comp = ($comp !== false) ? preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $comp) : false;
$ern = isset($_POST['ern']) ? $_POST['ern'] : false;
$ern = ($ern !== false) ? preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $ern) : false;


echo $ern[$comp]['value'];
```

Geting errors:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   D:\Tinklapis\Graffiz-CMS\php\update_order.php on line 7
>        Warning: Illegal string offset 'value' in D:\Tinklapis\Graffiz-CMS\php\update_order.php on line 9
>        Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in D:\Tinklapis\Graffiz-CMS\php\update_order.php on line 9

And nothing value printed.

Comment: Is that your actual code? No php tags anywhere?

Comment: Your title says POST but your code is using GET and POST.  Which one are you actually using?  Try  `var_dump` the one you're using and seeing what is actually in there after you submit the form.

Comment: Somethign isn't right about this piece: name='ern[".$row['ID']."][value]'. No php tags so I'm not sure but I know the single and double quotes probably are not matched correctly.

Comment: with var dump I get `array(5) { [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" } `

Comment: `ern[".$row['ID']."][value]` its like `ern[1][value], ern[2][value], ern[3][value]...`

Comment: fix the code in the question, please.

Comment: Which is line 7 and which is line 9? Help us to help you.

Comment: Line 7 seems to be your echo line and line 9 is beyond the shown sample.